# Slider Full-width problems on different screen sizes

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I have a full width jquery slider on my website, unfortunately, the images I have in that slider are shown in different positions depending on the size of the screen.

Does anyone have an idea where I could look at to fix that issue?

I use WordPress as CMS and the plugin is called "LayerSlider WP".

Comment: Please add your slider code.

Comment: It's a commercial plugin so why don't you ask the author on CodeCanyon? It does say it has a responsive mode (I don't know if you are using the most up to date version?), if it's on CodeCanyon there will have to be documentation that goes with it too.

Answer (score 0):

A link to the website and code would be really helpful. It sounds like for a full width slider, what you need to do is figure out the dimensions of the images, i.e. 960 x 1080, and then set the width height ratio of the slider accordingly using percent, and then set the position of the slider to be absolute. Add code and I will be able to help you more.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your position is the inline style you are putting on the image:

```
style="position: absolute; top: 24px; left: 326px...
```

That is conflicting with your responsive layout.

Comment: The plugin is putting that inline style automatically depending on where I drag and drop it in the admin panel.

Comment: What plugin and what admin panel? Please update your question with more information about what you are using and how.

Comment: Ok, done. Hopefully the information helps. Are any additional information required?

Comment: Yes that helps. But I can't help -- I don't do WordPress. I retagged the question so hopefully a WordPress user will see it and can help.

Comment: Ok, tku for your help! Much appreciated.